# ASP.NET MVC5 best way to keep track of sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-5, session-timeout

I am currently making a website using ASP.NET MVC5 and I need to keep track of active sessions (or to be more correct, a single value for each users session)

I have looked around and people seem to recommend Session_end() for this but all those recommendations are accompanied by people saying that session_end isn't reliable.

The reason I need to keep track of this is that users receive a unique folder to upload files to. This folder is deleted when a user completes the process but it remains if the website is closed without finishing it.
I currently save the value in a session variable (users should get a folder even when not logged in) and it is lost when the session expires. After the session expired, the folder should be deleted as no user can access it anymore (to save storage space).

I have access to a database, in case that helps for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the Session events are unreliable. As a rule of thumb playing with Session is almost never a good idea.

Now if I had to start from scratch with your requirements, I'd go with something that can actively monitor the active user connections on the web application.

Lucky for you there's a tool that does this and much more: SignalR. It's an ASP.NET component that allows to create responsive applications where multiple session can communicate with each other passing through the server. Applications like chats, dashboards and webgames are common applications of this library.

I suggest you to take a look at it and experiment a little, it has all you need to solve your current problem.